# How to set pressure sensitivity in GIMP to control line thickness?

Tags: 11.04, configuration, gimp, graphics-tablet, photoshop

My sister is moving from Windows and I just got her a new graphics tablet. However, the pressure sensitivity controls opacity rather than line thickness; she really needs this feature from Photoshop/Corel Painter.

Is there a way to toggle on or off the pressure affecting either line opacity or thickness?

Answer (score 25):

Make sure you have checked *Pressure: Size* in the *Brush Dynamics* section of the Toolbox:

[image]

If this still doesn't work, you probably haven't enabled the tablet. To do so, go to:

- *Edit → Preferences*
- *Input Devices → Configure Extended Input Devices*
- Choose your device and set it to *Screen* mode
- Save, close, and try again.

Answer (score 15):

On newer versions of Gimp the Brush Dynamics window will not look like that. Here is how it looks in Ubuntu 13.04:

[image]

If you click on the notepad to the right of "Pencil Generic copy", it will show the menu where you can select what pressure will do to the picture (opacity, size, etc.). But it is all disabled/greyed out. What you need to do is click on the crazy blue arrow, then click on the crazy blue arrow again, which will open the brush dynamics selection dialog. There you can select a brush and duplicate it. You will then be able to select the duplicate brush you just create, click on the notepad button, and then finally edit the brush dynamics as shown by htorque.

This has been tested in a Thinkpad X61 tablet running 13.04/raring and Gimp 2.8.4.

Comment: I cannot find the way to duplicate a brush dynamic as you say. P.S. Ah, found it, the second smaller crazy blue arrow is _below_ the list of all the other bigger blue crazy arrows.

Answer (score 2):

RE: Tablet not showing up in input devices
Hi....Information from

http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthre...ost2324411
on Post #13 as :
Download as : https://download.gimp.org/mirror/pub/gimp/v2.6/

Then I follow is work. But.. I Use Windows 10 my Gimp 2.6.9 Follow Below :

All,
I know this is a bit outdated (the last post was in October), but I've stumbled on a different, although more troublesome, way to enable pressure sensitivity in GIMP 2.8:

1. Plug tablet in.
2. Launch 2.6 (in this case I was using 2.6.12)
3. Go to File > Preferences > Input Devices > Configure Extended Input Devices...
   a. If you get an error saying no input devices found, close 2.6 and relaunch.
4. Draw something on the canvas using the tablet.
5. Close 2.6
6. Launch 2.8

You should now be able to draw in 2.8 with full pressure sensitivity. I'm not sure why this works, but I've tried it, rebooted my computer and tried it again with success. I am using Windows 8, but I believe it should work on all versions of Windows. Because OSX used X11 for 2.6, but not for 2.8 I'm unsure if this process would work.

Using Ubuntu 12.04 I was able to get 2.8 to handle pressure sensitivity right out of the box--but it could have been because I had just launched & closed 2.6 and had both installed side-by-side.

Like I said, this is a bit more cumbersome than the solution 2blackbar suggested above but I figured it was worth sharing.
Last edited by BnBGobo99; 28-May-13 at 15:13. Reason: Workflow was unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using a newer version of GIMP you just need to click on the arrow with three dots right of the text saying "Dynamics" then select the option you want to use, for example: "Pressure Size".

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you do not see the items Pressure, Velocity and Random you need to open those fields by clicking on "Brush Dynamics". This will unfold the three checkbox fields as shown in the screenshot. It took me an hour to find this out.